# how can i solve the "Value Error" which says could not convert string to float: 'D'?

Tags: pandas, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get the output using the same following expression but unable to fetch the details . can anyone please help?

```
# Separate into feature set and target variable
#FTR = Full Time Result (H=Home Win, D=Draw, A=Away Win)


import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn as s 
import matplotlib 
import tensorflow as tf 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from IPython.display import display 
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/patel/Desktop/tap.csv")
from IPython.display import display


X_all = df.drop(['FTR'],1)
y_all = df['FTR']

# Standardising the data.
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

#Center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance.
cols = [['FTHG','FTAG','HTHG','HTAG','HTR']]
for col in cols:
    X_all[col] = scale(X_all[col])

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fa9f01c17527> in <module>
     24 cols = [['FTHG','FTAG','HTHG','HTAG','HTR']]
     25 for col in cols:
---> 26     X_all[col] = scale(X_all[col])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in scale(X, axis, with_mean, with_std, copy)
    143     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, ensure_2d=False,
    144                     warn_on_dtype=True, estimator='the scale function',
--> 145                     dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES, force_all_finite='allow-nan')
    146     if sparse.issparse(X):
    147         if with_mean:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
503
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'D'

Comment: Presumably, you have string values in your data...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you `tap.csv` file. I'm assuming that you're facing this issue just because of some string values in your `.csv` file. In a normal view of your `.csv` file, you might see the data is structured in correct format, but it's not.